# For loop concatenation

Tags: php, for-loop, concatenation

So I had this one block of code that took first word of an array and wrapped it in a span but I need to do this to 2 different titles.

Instead of duplicating the same block of code which looks awfull I wanted to use a for loop, how do I concatenate $i with variable name or 'tytul1'?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    $calloutTitleExplode1 = explode(' ',trim($callout['tytul1']));
    $calloutTitleSpan1 = '<span>'.$calloutTitleExplode1[0].'</span> ';
    $calloutTitleShifted1 = array_shift($calloutTitleExplode1);
    $calloutTitleRest1 = implode(" ", $calloutTitleExplode1);
    $callout['tytul1'] = $calloutTitleSpan1 . $calloutTitleRest1;

    $calloutTitleExplode2 = explode(' ',trim($callout['tytul2']));
    $calloutTitleSpan2 = '<span>'.$calloutTitleExplode2[0].'</span> ';
    $calloutTitleShifted2 = array_shift($calloutTitleExplode2);
    $calloutTitleRest2 = implode(" ", $calloutTitleExplode2);
    $callout['tytul2'] = $calloutTitleSpan2 . $calloutTitleRest2;
}
```

Comment: Don't concatenate with a variable name, that's dumb. But for array accessed, `$callout['tytul'.$i]` concatenate like any other string.

Comment: Use `${"your_var_name_without_the_number$i"}` as your variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    ${"calloutTitleExplode$i"} = explode(' ',trim($callout["tytul$i"]));
    ${"calloutTitleSpan$i"} = '<span>'.${"calloutTitleExplode$i"}[0].'</span> ';
    ${"calloutTitleShifted$i"} = array_shift(${"calloutTitleExplode$i"});
    ${"calloutTitleRest$i"} = implode(" ", ${"calloutTitleExplode$i"});
    $callout["tytul$i"] = ${"calloutTitleSpan$i"} . ${"calloutTitleRest$i"};
}
```

This will create the var name dynamically using `$i`